# setting-up the web application when I use "\*" as url-pattern for DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc

I have mapped `DispatcherServlet` as follows

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ems</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ems</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

So, as per url it servers every request. But, when I mapped ViewResolver like this

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>      
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
```

and as the controller returns "home" as view name. Then I am getting

```
[PageNotFound] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ems/WEB-INF/jsps/home.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'ems'
```

As this InternalResourceViewResolver using RequestDispacher, it is going to be another request and that request again getting handled by `DispatcherServlet` again.

How can we resolve this issue? And what is the best way to define project structure when we use `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`. might be a dumb question, but I am always confused about defining my project structure when I use `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the "/*" for the URL mapping means that absolutely every request that's sent to that application has to go through the `DispatcherServlet`, so you'll need mappings for all of them.

If that's not acceptable, find a way to create a subset that should go through the `DispatcherSerlet` and let the rest be handled by the HTTP server.

Comment: when I changed this to "/" everything working fine. Can u explain me the reason of it?

Comment: "/" is the Unix slash that's used on the web; "\" is the Windows slash.  I don't know why one would work and the other not, but the first is what's typically used on the web.